# Enumerados Java

Tags: java

Hola gente estoy practicando con enumerados, me declare un enum Talla {MINI,MEDIANO,GRANDE,MUY_GRANDE};

Lo que quiero hacer sin constructor es que dependiendo de la talla que ingrese el usuario (S,M,L,XL) evaluarlo con un if  y decirle si es de tipo {MINI,MEDIANO,GRANDE,MUY_GRANDE}

```
    Talla s = Talla.MINI;
    Talla m = Talla.MEDIANO;
    Talla l = Talla.GRANDE;
    Talla xl = Talla.MUY_GRANDE;
    Scanner entrada = new 
    Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escribe una Talla: 
    S,M,L,XL");

    String entrada_datos=entrada.next().toUpperCase() ;
```

Precisaría ayuda con la lógica. Mi pseudocódigo seria:

```
If (entrada_datos == "s")

System.out.println("Talla=" + tipo de enum);
```

por ejemplo.

Gracias saludos.

Comment: Cuando compares cadenas de caracteres, tienes que hacerlo con el método `equals()` o `equalsIgnoreCase()`, por ejemplo: `if ("s".equalsIgnoreCase(entrada_datos))`. Si comparas un literal con una variable, es recomendable llamar al método `equals` del literal, ya que este nunca va a ser `null`, y la variable podría serlo y obtendrías un `NullPointerException`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Necesitaría definir tu `enum` de este modo:

```
public enum Talla {
    S("MINI"),
    M("MEDIANO"),
    L("GRANDE"),
    XL("MUY_GRANDE");


    private String text;

    Talla(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }

    public String text() {
        return text;
    }
}
```

Luego, para recuperar el texto de cada uno sólo tienes que hacer algo como:

```
    System.out.println(Talla.S.text());  //MINI
    System.out.println(Talla.M.text());  //MEDIANO
    System.out.println(Talla.L.text());  //GRANDE
    System.out.println(Talla.XL.text());  //MUY_GRANDE
```

---

Si quieres hacerlo sin métodos, como dices, puedes escribir el código así simplemente:

```
enum Talla {
    S("MINI"),
    M("MEDIANO"),
    L("GRANDE"),
    XL("MUY_GRANDE");


    private String text;

    Talla(String text) {
        this.text = text;
    }
}

    try 
    {
            System.out.println("Talla=" + Talla.valueOf(entrada_datos));
    }
    catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
    {
             System.out.println("No existe: "+ entrada_datos + " en el Enum");
    }
```

Hay que manejar la posible excepción `IllegalArgumentException` por si el usuario escribe un valor que no exista en el Enum.

Con eso bastaría, no veo la necesidad de usar un `if`.

Si de todos modos quieres usar un `if`, no te está funcionando porque para comparar cadenas tienes que usar `equals`, no `==`. Si pones el `if` así debería funcionar:

```
if ( entrada_datos.equals("S") ) {
```

Comment: Muchas gracias @A.Cedano, exactamente asi fue como lo hice la primera prueba queria hacerlo sin metedos.

Comment: @RichardBrancato revisa la respuesta editada, al final. Tu código no funciona porque debes usar `equals` en la comparación.

Comment: Ahora si Impecable!! muchas gracias.

Answer (score 0):

No logro hacer que evalue el if,
probe con un else y si muestra lo que quiero por consola.

```
Scanner entrada = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Escribe una Talla: S,M,L,XL");

    String entrada_datos=entrada.next().toUpperCase() ;
    //System.out.println(entrada_datos);


    if ( entrada_datos == "S" ) {

        System.out.println("Talla=" + Talla.MINI );

    }   
    else {
        System.out.println("Talla=" + Talla.MEDIANO );
    }
```

Esto es lo despliega por consola

```
Escribe una Talla: S,M,L,XL,S
Talla=MEDIANO
```

Comment: Aquí sólo van las respuestas a tu pregunta. Si necesitas añadir información, por favor edita tu pregunta.